# Обновить widget при изменения данных сайта http/https

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

Я сделала виджет) который показывает статистику и новости, с сайта. Всё работает отлично. Я хочу чтоб он обновлялся, когда данные страницы меняются. Первая идея была делать запрос, и если данные изменились, то выводить уже к примеру уведомление."новые новости". Но начала читать и пишут, что это антипаттерн, так делать нельзя, тк батарея садится. А как тогда сделать? Есть ли возможность обновить виджет сразу, после такого как изменились определенные данные на страничке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть мысль использовать Push-уведомления и обновлять данные, когда придет пуш на устройство. Идея такая: веб-мастер правит страницу - посылается пуш на девайс - а далее несколько вариантов: либо особый запрос слать на сервер, либо какие-то данные получать из пуша. Но максимальный размер пуша - 4КБ.

Ну и способ влоб вы уже частично описали: запрос в AlarManager, который например раз в час будет долбить сервер и обновлять виджет.

Comment: Да, да я читала но ничего не поняла про Push - уведомления. Информации вроде много, но вся размыта, четкой реализации нет. Мне бы какой-нибудь простой пример, для личного пользования, или любая информация. На словах всё вроде красиво, а как сделать нигде нет.

Comment: С английским дружите? Например вводная статья: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Кроме того сервер тоже должен быть настроен на посылку пушей. Это уже работа веб-разработчика.

Comment: Архитектура вцелом: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm

Comment: те крупные сайты новостей скорей всего настроены на работу с push ? Да статья очень хорошая, англ. свободно читаю.

Comment: Не уверен. Тот кто его разрабатывает вам ответит.

Comment: А можно как-то проверить, а то сейчас начну делать а окажется что всё зря

Comment: Без людей, которые делали этот сайт никак не проверить. Можете только найти мобильные приложения для данного сайта (если есть) и посмотреть реализовано ли подобное в них.

Comment: Спасибо большое за советы, буду читать)